# Using lookup tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lookup-tables

I've had to use a lookup table in an EF project and it took me a bit of tinkering to get it working but I'm unsure how to query something.

If I have three tables (this is a test project to illustrate the question):

```
Person
------
ID - Int - PK
PersonName - varchar[50]
```

and

```
Skill
-----
ID - Int - PK
SkillName - varchar[50]
```

which are linked by a lookup table:

```
PS_Lookup
---------
ID - Int - PK
PersonID - Int - FK : Person.ID
SkillID - Int - FK : Skill.ID
```

Now, if I want to return all users who have a skill of ID 1 I've worked out I can do:

```
var result = (from p in context.People                          
              select new
              {
                  PersonID = p.ID,
                  PersonName = p.PersonName,
                  FirstSkill = (from s in p.PS_Lookup 
                                where s.ID == 1
                                select s.SkillName),                              
              }).ToList();
```

My question is, what do I need to change on the above query just to return the PersonName and PersonID of everyone who has the skill with the ID 1?
i.e. Not returning "FirstSkill". I don't need the name as I know what FirstSkill is and I can't see what I have to do with the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use where condition in your query:

```
var result = (from p in context.People
              where p.PS_Lookup.Any(ps => ps.ID == 1)
              select new { p.ID, p.PersonName })
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Marvellous, thank you. I've just about got used to Linq but it still trips me up now and again.